# How a verify a page in transition using selenium

Tags: firefox, selenium, android-uiautomator

I clicked on a button on some page which redirects me to some other page.but between these pages there is one page which comes only for 1 or 2 seconds. I have to verify that page.I am using selenium.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

What you could do here, is do a simple `waitForElement` subroutine.

Ideally, when your test framework cannot find an element to operate with, it will fail.

So we can assume, that when your test gets past `waitForElement(theInterimElement)` then your interim element **has** appeared, and we can continue.

Comment: you might have misunderstood it.Actually i have to verify that intermedite page itself, but thats just appearing for 1-2 secs , so in that time no xpaths are found.

Answer (score 0):

Check the url of the page is the url of the desired page and wait while this is not true.

```
while (!webDriver.Url.Contains(desiredUrl.ToString()))
    Thread.Sleep(50);
```

Comment: URL doesn't change when that page comes.